# Connection a Usb 2.0 driver to a usb 2.0 port using a 3.0 extension cable

Tags: usb, usb-3, usb-2

I have a usb 2.0 Audio driver for my headphone and a usb 2.0 mouse, and i have 2 usb 2.0 ports and 2 usb 3.0 ports., I wanted to buy a usb extension for both of them because i need the extra length, I was going to buy a standard usb 2.0 extension, but then i was wondering if i buy a new mouse with usb 3.0 i will need to change the extension, and same for the headphone, So my question is If i buy a usb 3.0 extension, will it work between a usb 2.0 port and usb 2.0 device, or should i just buy the 2.0 extension ?

Comment: Just so you know, the USB spec does not allow extension cables.  None of them can be found to meet the USB spec because there is no spec that defines how they should work.  While they often do work they can cause issues with the attached devices.  Just how far are you extending the cables?  You can't find a way to shorten the distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mice don't use USB3, and are unlikely to *require* it in the near future.

That said, all that will happen with a USB 3.0 extension cable is that the additional connectors won't be connected to anything, and things should just work.

Comment: Thank you, i will buy the usb 3.0 extension then, since i might use it with my usb 3.0 external hard drives xD